# Root Mean Square Error of the addition of two measurements whose RMS Error is known

Tags: error, rms, noise

I am working on a measurement system which tries to measure the distance between two values i.e $\Delta F=F_1-F_2$. Where $F_1, F_2$ are the values I actually measure. I have set up a Monte Carlo simulation to calculate the error I expect when making this measurement under different noise conditions. I wanted to compare my results to those theoretically predicted, but while I do have theoretical values for the RMS error of $F_1, F_2$ I do not know if there is a way to combine these error to get my expected RMS error in $\Delta F$. Is it possible to do this calculation and if so under what conditions?

Thank You,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMSE with respect to what number/target exactly? If it's the mean (or expected value of each variable) you're comparing these numbers to, then I've got some good news about MSE/Variance in the theoretical side of the house:

$$V[\Delta F]=E\left[(\Delta F-E[\Delta F])^2\right] = E\left[((F_1-F_2)-E[F_1-F_2])^2\right] = E\left[((F_1-F_2)-E[F_1]-(-E[F_2]))^2\right]=E\left[((F_1-E[F_1])-(F_2-E[F_2]))^2\right]=E\left[(F_1-E[F_1])^2+(F_2-E[F_2])^2-2(F_1-E[F_1])(F_2-E[F_2])\right] = E\left[(F_1-E[F_1])^2\right]+E\left[(F_2-E[F_2])^2\right]-2E\left[(F_1-E[F_1])(F_2-E[F_2])\right]=V[F_1]+V[F_2]-2\text{COV}[F_1,F_2]$$

All you would need to know would be the covariance between $F_1$ and $F_2$. And of course if you want RMSE or standard deviation instead of MSE or variance you can slap some square roots on both sides.

If you're measuring RMSE wrt some other target then the story might be a little different, but I think you could apply similar manipulations to get an idea of RMSE for $\Delta F$.